# set up scheduler for direct mail in typo3 6.0.2

Tags: typo3, newsletter

please I don't know how to invoke mailer engine automatically in direct mail typo3 6.0.2 any ideas? thank you.

Comment: Is it that you don't know how to use the scheduler at all or just in 6.0?

Comment: I don't know how to use it at all, but i specified version in case there is an other configuration

Answer (score 0):

Some basics that might help to get into it:

The scheduler allows you to set up only one cron job on the server and comfortably manage various recurring tasks from the backend (as opposed to setting up a single cron job for each task).

Step 1: You set up one cron job on the server that kicks off the scheduler once in a while. Refer to your host for informations on how to do that and to the scheduler manual for the path. Make sure you set the correct path to php. This cron hits, say, every 5 minutes.

Step 2: In the scheduler module, you can now add tasks by clicking the "new item" icon on top left.
Only tasks provided by the system and by extensions appear here. If direct_mail is installed, you will find the direct mail mailing queue task. Add it. Here, you can enter a frequency in which the task should run. You can use either seconds or crontab syntax. It can't run more often than the main scheduler, of course, so not all combinations make sense: If the scheduler runs every 5 minutes, you can't push the direct_mail mailing queue every 3 minutes.

Step 3: if it doesn't work, look at the paths

Step 4: add more scheduler tasks, like auto-update the extension repository etc.

Links:
- There is a detailed manual for the scheduler as well as for direct_mail. Get them in the extensions module.
- Good tutorial on direct_mail http://blog.undkonsorten.com/typo3-newsletter-direct-mail-subscription (in German, like many TYPO3 resources)